# Where to find the latest news on sustainability issues?

Tags: law, internet

I am looking for recommendations for websites, journals, blogs, and magazines that one could turn to to find the latest news and research on issues of sustainability, without (or at least with minimal) editorializing or politicizing.

Such sources would provide reporting on:

- The latest research on environmental effects of GMOs
- Advances in solar PV technology
- Proposed or enacted legislation/regulation relating to distributed generation, fuel subsidies, etc
- Recent data or analysis relating to climate change

Since opinions (by the public, prominent public figures, and/or politicians) on such topics are often news items in themselves, these sources could report on such opinions, but ideally they would not offer opinions of their own.

Comment: Please note that questions asking for resources are often closed as "too broad" on most StackExchange websites because there usually isn't a single, objectively-best answer. There is always room for one more recommendation. However given [this recent discussion on meta](http://meta.sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/249/do-we-want-community-wiki-resources-posts) and the fact that your question scope is fairly narrow, we will not close this question. I do think that when there are a lot of answers, we'd better turn this into a community-wiki question.

Comment: This should be community wiki, since the mods don't seem inclined to delete it as "there is no single, correct answer". You're explicitly asking for a list of resources rather than an answer.

Comment: @Móż after rereading my own [meta post](http://meta.sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/249/do-we-want-community-wiki-resources-posts) and given the widened scope of this question, I've made this a community-wiki question.

Comment: I disagree, this question is way too broad. I could dump dozens of links from my RSS reader which would all meet the requirements of the OP, and which would *only* cover the 'climate change' bullet point looked at from a scientific standpoint (i.e. excluding politics etc). With 160 million Google results on the term *sustainability* the possibilities are endless. If the OP limited the question to one subject only, maybe it's OK.

Comment: @JanDoggen, I also felt the question might be too broad... BUT, it seems to me like sustainability.SE would be well-served by a community wiki with a dozen or so good resources for news on sustainability. These would be curated links, rather than a dump from google, where searching for sustainability includes junk blogs and corporations "green-washing" their products. So, if you've got a dozen or so in your RSS feed... what are a few of your favorites?

Comment: I suggest we narrow done the scope of this question and try to make it less subjective (e.g. focus on objective news about sustainability research). You can always ask another (community-wiki) resource question if the need arises.

Comment: Perhaps a better question would be asking about a scientific or academic journal focusing on research in the area of sustainability, whether regarding technology, sociology, economics, agriculture, or public policy. Should I edit this question, or add a new one?

Comment: @LShaver Normally I'd say create a new question because your proposed edit would make existing answers invalid. But since the only answer is written by me (and it's community wiki) you can go ahead and edit this question. I'll revise my answer after your edit.

Answer (score 2):

- [**Science Daily**](https://www.sciencedaily.com/news/) is a good one. It discusses new scientific articles in a way that is understandable for non-scientists and it provides a link to the original article so you can read it yourself. The site has quite a bit of interesting subtopics. Just to name a few:

  - [sustainability](https://www.sciencedaily.com/news/earth_climate/sustainability/)
  - [recycling and waste](https://www.sciencedaily.com/news/earth_climate/recycling_and_waste/)
  - [pollution](https://www.sciencedaily.com/news/earth_climate/pollution/)
  - [global warming](https://www.sciencedaily.com/news/earth_climate/global_warming/)
  - [alternative fuels](https://www.sciencedaily.com/news/matter_energy/alternative_fuels/)
  - [solar energy](https://www.sciencedaily.com/news/matter_energy/solar_energy/)
  - [wind energy](https://www.sciencedaily.com/news/matter_energy/wind_energy/)
  - [GMOs](https://www.sciencedaily.com/news/plants_animals/genetically_modified/)
  - [Environmental policy](https://www.sciencedaily.com/news/earth_climate/environmental_policy/)

  The only confusing part of the website is that a lot of subtopics aren't visible in the menu at the top, but a bit lower on the page on the menu on the left.
- For a general overview on several environmental issues there's also the **[Environmental Health Network](https://www.ehn.org/)**. You can subscribe to their mailing list, which is divided by topics (check their options) and you can set the frequency as well.
- Alternatively there are a few newspapers that have a section dedicated to sustainable living, e.g. [The NY times](http://www.nytimes.com/topic/subject/sustainable-living) or [The Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/news/sustainability/). However topics don't always relate to research and the newspapers may be politically biased.